Windows extremely slow, doesn't sleep when closed, BIOS screen when closed
A week ago I found that my computer had suddenly become extremely slow. Both Windows processes and the browser take a very long time to load. For example, the BIOS start time hovers around 40 seconds. For context, I am running windows 10 on an Acer Predator PT314-51s. (SNID: 14701332934) I have tried the following things:

Deleting bloatware

Disabling startup tasks

Updating windows

Acer care diagnostics

Windows settings diagnostics

Defragging the hard disk

Performing a clean boot

Booting into safe mode (no networking)

Contacting Acer support -Updating drivers

Updating BIOS and firmware

sfc/scannow

DISM scan

Windows memory diagnostic

Windows disc check (CHKDSK)

Reinstalling windows from a thumb drive, and preventing syncing by not connecting to the internet during reinstallation


None of these were able to find or fix the problem.
Linked are my windows bootlog, and windows errors logged on Event Viewer.
